# Find Disconnect Graph with Degree Sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

**Could you find a disconnected graph with degree sequence (7,6,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,2,2)?**

> I tried havel hakimi theorem but it is for there is graph exist or
>   not. Solution is yes it is exist. But how can we know that it is
>   disconnect or not. I tried to figure it out. I draw from Havel Hakimi
>   basic. It is connected, but it is not a proof.

*Thank you for your answers in advance.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume there is a disconnected graph with this degree sequence. Since one vertex is connected to $7$ others, there is a connected component of size at least $8$. This means there must be a connected component of size at most $3$.
If there is a component of size $3$, the degrees of its vertices can be at most $2$, but there are only $2$ such vertices available, contradiction.
If there is a component of size $<3$, the degrees of its vertices can be at most $1$, there are no such vertices, contradiction.

Therefore, such a disconnected graph cannot exist.

Comment: I didn't understand "This means there must be a connected component of size at most 3." part. I can not understand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29 is :(

Comment: disconnected means that your graph is cut into several "potatoes" (at least $2$) with no edge between each other. "Connected component" is the name for "potato". If a potato is of size at least $8$, and the total number of vertices is $11$, this means at most $3$ vertices are left for other potatoes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a vertex with degree $7$, hence there is a connected component with at least $8$ vertices. The vertices not lying in this component are at most $3$, but for any subsets of three vertices, the sum of their degrees exceeds $6$, hence the graph, if existing (and it does exist by the Havel-Hakimi theorem) must be connected.